# Using SQL Server data in Google Big Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection, google-bigquery

I need some help in using the data that resides in SQL Server to be accessed from Google Big Query for the analytics.

I have all the transaction data in SQL Server and now we want to run some analytics on top of data using Big Query. But I didn't find a way to connect the data from the SQL Server.

Comment: maybe this help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6056421f-c868-4d7b-9dd1-a40dc4216eaa/connect-google-bigquery-to-sql-server-with-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: That's the opposite direction. BigQuery doesn't have a native connector for SQL Server, but you can either do the process yourself (export, upload to GCS, then import) or use a third-party; [Alooma](https://www.alooma.com/integrations/to/bigquery) is one such example, although I'm sure you can find plenty of others using a Google search.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza is there a way to upload the database file (I mean .mdf) to GCS and then import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull a CSV using `sqlcmd`, and then upload that to BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate all your SQL Server data to Google BigQuery without a CSV step using 3rd parties tools. Most of them can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest the following way:

1. Instead of CSV you can take the back up in JSON file as well. It will improve the performance. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 100 XYZ,ABC FROM TABLE1 FOR JSON PATH
```

And using SQLCMD you can save it in Local.

2. Upload the same in GCS.
3. Create table in Bigquery from the data in GCS.